# Which hosting technology is suitable for large data with limited index

Tags: mysql, nosql

I have a scenario where I have to host very large amount of data in database type solution. The amount of data is very very large. When I try to host it in mysql database the size increases as mysql adds pre calculated information to the data. Which solution will be suitable for this type of data. Keep in mind

1. I do not need any complicated functions such as average, sum, distinct etc.
2. I only need 2 columns to run where clause to pull the data. I plan to do the rest in the GUI
3. The amount users are very limited (less than 100) nationwide
4. Most of the data is integers. Some of them are int64. It is in a tabular form. Only two column one being dataTime type.

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators! This is an interesting question and you are in the right place, but it would be good to know much more about your problem... What kind of data is it? What would the two columns be? How much data will you typically be retrieving, and what kind of querying will you do? How often does the data get written to? If you can't provide exact details due to confidentiality, please think of a equivalent example.

Comment: Two more questions - what didn't work about MySQL? Why did you decide to 'do the rest in the GUI'?

Comment: MySQL is working fine. I need a solution which will consume less space. Pushing calculations to GUI not a big problem in this case. Data space is the problem.

Comment: More than a billion rows?  What indexes do you need?  How do you shovel the data into the table(s)?  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Please show us a query that you are worried about.